# Pass parameters to MapReduce in Mongo and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mongodb

I have a Dictionary that I'd like to pass as JS to the Map part of my Map Reduce query. Is this possible or even an appropriate thing to want to do?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `scope` option to send params to map/reduce/finalize functions

as per the [doc](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce)

```
db.runCommand(
 { mapreduce : <collection>,
   map : <mapfunction>,
   reduce : <reducefunction>
   [, query : <query filter object>]
   [, sort : <sorts the input objects using this key. Useful for optimization, like sorting by the emit key for fewer reduces>]
   [, limit : <number of objects to return from collection>]
   [, out : <see output options below>]
   [, keeptemp: <true|false>]
   [, finalize : <finalizefunction>]
   [, scope : <object where fields go into javascript global scope >]
   [, jsMode : true]
   [, verbose : true]
 }
);
```

> scope - can pass in variables that can be access from
>   map/reduce/finalize.

check out the usage from [here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/jstests/core/mr5.js#L28)

excerpt from the link

```
   res = t.mapReduce( m , r , { out : "mr5_out" , scope : { xx : 1 } } );
```

I dont have much experience with c# driver, but based on the above example you can jsonify your object and assign it to scope. That will do the trick

Hope this helps